# Controller is not found in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Home page link is:

```
<a href="view_pre_read/?tid=22">Click here to go</a>
```

routing code is:

```
$route['view_pre_read/(:any)'] = 'view_pre_read/$1';
$route['view_pre_read'] = 'view_pre_read';
```

and my controller is:

```
class View_pre_read extends CI_Controller {

    function index(){
        $tid=$_REQUEST['tid'];
            $this->load->view('pages/notopic',$data);
    }

}
```

but its always going to call 404 error page;

Please any one help me how to overcome this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use base_url() in the link

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your controller file name is correct or not.

Comment: This looks more like a comment!

Comment: @AfghanWiz : I can't able to comment bcoz of i have less than 50 reputation.

Comment: You have +50 rep now. I think this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all from the documentation:

```
(:num) will match a segment containing only numbers.
(:any) will match a segment containing any character.
```

So why not use `(:num)` in your case ?

In your controller you must retrieve the value of `tid` by adding it in your method parameter. I guess that the missing parameter induce the missing route. Moreover, I don't think it's a good idea to use `$_REQUEST`. I guess that CI implement some functions to get parameters from `$_REQUEST`.

```
class View_pre_read extends CI_Controller {

    function index($tid) { // Add the $tid here
        echo $tid; //print 22
        //$tid=$_REQUEST['tid'];
        $this->load->view('pages/notopic',$data);
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

I have not picked a long look to your route... Maybe you should add which method you call.

```
$route['view_pre_read/(:num)'] = "view_pre_read/index/$1";
```

Will result in `http://yourwebsite.com/view_pre_read/index/22`.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /dashboard_new4/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: class View_pre_read extends CI_Controller {

    function index($tid) { // Add the $tid here
        echo $tid; //print 22
        //$tid=$_REQUEST['tid'];
        $this->load->view('pages/notopic',$data);
    }

}

Comment: @GangaU: Just update your question instead of putting many comments. I have no more ideas, it should works. Maybe your link `<a>` isn't correct. What happens if you tried to access the URL in the browser ? (`http://yourwebsite.com/view_pre_read/22`) By the way, be sure that your `class name` is equal to your `file.php`